# Auto share link on Facebook page

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I have a [website] done in ASP.NET, http://www.website.com and a facebook page http://www.facebook.com/website

Posts are added to the site and then approved by publishers. Each post has a unique url ***[website]/post/this-is-unique-url-for-this-post*** As soon as the post is approved by the publishers, I want to take that unique url and share it on the facebook page automagically!

I looked into the facebook sharer but I couldn't find a solution that does this without user intervention.

Is this even possible? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers :)

Comment: I think that since this is a new user, it would have been a bit more polite for whoever downvoted this question give some adivce to the user on how to improve the question.

Wrack. I would suggest maybe adding some code on what you've done already, or maybe do a search on the site as I think there may be some other questions, with answers that may help you.

Comment: Thanks JRSofty. I did do a search but could not find anything that I was looking for. May be my search terms were wrong to begin with. I will continue looking and will post a sample code of what I have done so far so it may help other to see where the problem is and help me out.